# Excel conditional formatting formula to column

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formatting

I want to apply a conditional formatting formula on all the cells of columns *A* by highlighting it. Basically on each row of column *A* I have a different name. On column *F* and *H* I have numbers. For example taking cell *A1*, then on *F1* I have the number "3", if I also have the number "3" on cell *H1* automatically is going to highlight *A1*. I want to apply it to all the cells in column *A*.

How can I make it?

Comment: How about `=F1=H1`?

Comment: It works but how can I apply it automatically respect to each row of column A, F and H?

Answer (score 1):

Create a conditional formatting rule based on the formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(F1),F1=H1)
```

and apply it to all rows in A containing data.